# How to keep master history short and clear in git?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have 2 remotes repository for a project.

1(origin) is my private repo where I make my modification to the project.
2(upstream) is the original github repo where I cloned(--bare) from.

From time to time, I get updates from the upstream and merge it to master, and it works well.
However when I see the commit history, all commits from both repositories(origin/upstream) are shown and its hard to tell what changed where.(especially our inhouse commits)

What's the good strategy to keep the master branch history clean?

I came up with an idea, but wasn't sure if it will work or good enough.

create a branch in origin repository to be used solely for `merging-in upstream` changes.
   After merge upstream to this branch(let's call it merge_branch), I merge the merge_branch to master hoping to see only 1 aggregated commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what your current method really is... However what you describe as the new idea sound like the usual way.

Your repo should look like this:

- `master` branch with the final state (tracks `origin/master`)
- `upstream` branch (tracks `upstream/master`)

At start and later point you merge the upstream branch into master. Direct commits on mastr are your work. It's up to taste whether you push the 'upstream' branch itself to `origin` too, the merge commits normally are informative enough.

EDIT: 
After discussion it's getting clear what you're after. 
To see the whole upstream as a single commit, you have to merge with --squash.

It is something I'd consider an unusual use of upstream, but can make sense. If you do that, I suggest to run the `upstream` branch as above to keep ability to see original commits too (both on local and origin), merge with squash and in commit message note the hash of the upstream branch (deleting the commit list).

Comment: ah I had upstream/mater but no local upstream branch.(merged upstream/master directly to master)

Comment: that way is practically the same as the described one, the only difference I see is in default commit message in merge.

Comment: ok.. I created local up branch(which tracks upstream/master) and pulled upstream/master into it.  then merged it to local/master. I expected to see `aggreated` commit history(see only 1 merge commit from local/up) but I still see the whole list of commit history of upstream/master. so I guess this is expected and no way around.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question, I want to see smaller set of history log for my master(excluding upstream/master commits)

Comment: ok make sense, I looked at other use of squash and notice people use it for merging in local branches. Why do you say it's `unusual use of upstream` though?

Comment: just my subjective observation, feel free to ignore it :).  Possibly it depends much on the nature of the upstream.